# Install openSuse on Centos server With usb drive

Tags: centos, opensuse

I have an system with Centos server installed on it. I want it to change into OpenSuse 13.2

Unfortunatly the usb drive i have created with ImageUSB is not recognized as bootable Device. Im not able to install Open Suse. Do you guys have some tips or tricks to help me?

Comment: you can try to install it from CD/DVD

Comment: I tried an DVD, but unfortunately still doesn't recognize

Comment: What devices are visible in BIOS in BOOT sequence?

Comment: I added, usb and cd. Removed sata. I made a new DVD it did boot, but half way through installation the pc shutdown by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use a program called [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) on windows to create the bootable USB. It has never failed me.

Just make sure to click the checkbox that says **Create a bootable disk using ISO Image** and select your Suse image.

Otherwise on CentOS you can install LiveUSB-Creator which is a CentOS/Fedora app which you can use to create a bootable USB. Just install using:  `yum install liveusb-creator`

Comment: I tried doing that, weirdly it still doesnt recognize it when i try to boot my pc

Comment: have you tried it in another PC? can your PC boot any other image from a USB?